# EmguCV write H.264/MPEG-4 AVC files using VideoWriter

Tags: video, h.264, mp4, emgucv

Is there any way to write H.264/MPEG-4 AVC videos using VideoWriter in EmguCV? I have attempted and it throws an InvalidOperationException where WriteFrame is invoked. By the way I am new to EmguCV. Please help.

here is my code

```
Image<Bgr, byte> img0 = new Image<Bgr, byte>("1.jpg");

VideoWriter v = new VideoWriter("5.mp4",-1, 1, 1920, 1080, true);

v.WriteFrame(img0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am still new at this but i realized when using a file name with the extension '.avi' it pop up a dialog when using -1 as the second parameter. but when i try anything else such as mpeg or mp4 it doesnt do anything.